# I'm unable to import sqlite3 or knex-js in to electron react app

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

When I import sqlite3 to try and test my database connection I get an error, when I opened the development tools I found this stating:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.path (external "path":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js (sqlite3.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object.<anonymous> (App.tsx:3)
    at Object../src/App.tsx (App.tsx:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
path    @   external "path":1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:789
fn  @   bootstrap:100
./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js   @   sqlite3.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:789
fn  @   bootstrap:100
(anonymous) @   App.tsx:3
./src/App.tsx   @   App.tsx:22
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:789
fn  @   bootstrap:100
./src/renderer.tsx  @   renderer.tsx:4
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:789
fn  @   bootstrap:100
0   @   renderer.tsx:6
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:789
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:856
(anonymous)
```

and this is the code I wrote:

```
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database("./database.sqlite", (err: any) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log("Connected to database");
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <h2>sdfsdfs </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default hot(module)(App);
```

I'm using Electron, React, Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Do not connect sqlite directly with React components. Make the application core separate and connect with the frontend using Electron IPC.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)